# Couldn't store job: Driver's Blob representation is of an unsupported type: oracle.sql.BLOB [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, spring, oracle, quartz-scheduler, jboss6.x

When I deploy only in JBOSS on Oracle i am facing this issue. Tried copying odbc6_g.jar in to oracle classpath also did not work for me.

```
INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) JBAS018210: Register web context: /syncservice
10:03:00,032 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/syncservice]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) Spring WebApplicati
onInitializers detected on classpath: [org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer@56e537d]
10:03:09,855 ERROR [com.kony.sync.console.job.scheduler.ConsoleJobScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) Some error in scheduling Cron job.: org.quar
tz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store job: Driver's Blob representation is of an unsupported type: oracle.sql.BLOB [See nested exception: java.sql.SQL
Exception: Driver's Blob representation is of an unsupported type: oracle.sql.BLOB]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1132) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$3.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1071) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3716) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3788) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:90) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3712) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJobAndTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1059) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:822) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:243) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at com.kony.sync.console.job.scheduler.ConsoleJobScheduler.schedulePaaSJob(ConsoleJobScheduler.java:328) [syncconsole.jar:]
        at com.kony.sync.services.context.SyncContextListener.contextInitialized(SyncContextListener.java:145) [classes:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1
]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redh
at-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-re
dhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-
14]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Driver's Blob representation is of an unsupported type: oracle.sql.BLOB
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate.writeDataToBlob(OracleDelegate.java:647) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate.insertJobDetail(OracleDelegate.java:207) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1126) [quartz-all-1.8.6.jar:]
        ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding dependency for oracle driver jar in MANIFEST.MF solved my problem